# Completion block for nested requests

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, request, completion

I am trying to build methods with completion blocks for nested requests. The issue is that a completion block catches to early for parent requests (meaning that the child requests haven't actually completed yet). So far I haven't found a way for a child request to communicate back to the parent request other than what I've done in my example below (which is to count the amount of child requests have completed and compare it against the expected amount of requests).

The example below is working against a Firestore database. Imagine a user has multiple card games (decks) with each multiple cards. I'm grateful for any help how to build better completion blocks for cases like these:

```
func fetchCardsCount(uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()


    var decksCount = Int()
    var cardsCount = Int()

    db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("decks").getDocuments { (deckSnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error fetching decks for user: ", err)
        } else {
            guard let deckSnapshot = deckSnapshot else { return }

            deckSnapshot.documents.forEach({ (deck) in
                let dictionary = deck.data() as [String: Any]
                let deck = FSDeck(dictionary: dictionary)
                db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("decks").document(deck.deckId).collection("cards").getDocuments(completion: { (cardSnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error fetching cards for deck: ", err)
                    } else {
                        guard let cardSnapshot = cardSnapshot else { return }
                        decksCount += 1
                        cardsCount += cardSnapshot.count

                        if decksCount == deckSnapshot.count {
                            completion(cardsCount)
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DispatchGroup might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @meggar Mind elaborating? It's not apparent to me how putting a task on another thread would help catching a completion?

Comment: I was thinking `completion(cardsCount)` would be moved outside the `forEach` loop, since it looks like that's where it belongs if I'm reading it correctly.  Then, if  the requests for "cards" are on other threads, the dispatchGroup can be used to wait for them to complete.

Comment: @meggar gotcha - I've never used dispatch group for this case. How would you write that?

Comment: the dispatchGroup would be created before the `forEach` loop, then add a `dispatchGroup.enter()` as the first line inside the `forEach` loop, and a `dispatchGroup.leave()` as the last line inside the completion. then add a `dispatchGroup.notify(...)` after the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, using DispatchGroup, found with @meggar's help in the comments:

```
func fetchCardsCount(uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    var cardsCount = Int()
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("decks").getDocuments { (deckSnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error fetching decks for user: ", err)
        } else {
            guard let deckSnapshot = deckSnapshot else { return }

            deckSnapshot.documents.forEach({ (deck) in
                let dictionary = deck.data() as [String: Any]
                let deck = FSDeck(dictionary: dictionary)

                group.enter()
                db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("decks").document(deck.deckId).collection("cards").getDocuments(completion: { (cardSnapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error fetching cards for deck: ", err)
                    } else {
                        guard let cardSnapshot = cardSnapshot else { return }
                        cardsCount += cardSnapshot.count
                    }
                    group.leave()
                })
            })
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(cardsCount)
    }
}
```